# Why Bootstrap table do not use styles in Angular 7?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular7

I try to create simple bootstrap table in Angular 7.2 project however it does not use any styles. I just see raw text. Any ideas why it does not work?

component.ts:

```
elements: any = [
    {id: 1, first: 'Mark', last: 'Otto', handle: '@mdo'},
    {id: 2, first: 'Jacob', last: 'Thornton', handle: '@fat'},
    {id: 3, first: 'Larry', last: 'the Bird', handle: '@twitter'},
  ];

  headElements = ['ID', 'First', 'Last', 'Handle'];
```

component.html:

```
<table mdbTable striped="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let head of headElements" scope="col">{{head}} </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let el of elements">
      <th scope="row">{{el.id}}</th>
      <td>{{el.first}}</td>
      <td>{{el.last}}</td>
      <td>{{el.handle}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

angular.json:

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "src/assets/sass/paper-kit.scss",
      "src/assets/css/demo.css",
      "src/assets/css/nucleo-icons.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ],
```

styles.scss:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

app.modules.ts:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
imports: [
    ...,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ],
 ...
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Comment: It seems like you are using `mdbootstrap` - https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/tables/basic/ for that you need to install `angular-bootstrap-md` package. If you want to use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/ add class `table` to the table tag -> `<table class="table table-striped">`.

Answer (score 0):

To use Bootstrap table, just add the class `table`, for striped, add `table-striped`

```
<table  class="table table-striped">
</table
```

But your HTML shows you have used [mdbootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-md). You need to install **angular-bootstrap-md**

> npm i angular-bootstrap-md